I get PHPMailer SMTP Error while useing Go54 shared Host
I am trying to sent email using SMTP (PHP Mailer). I am using the aws SMS service. Below is my code:
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host     = 'email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = '---';
$mail->Password = '---';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port     = 587;

I gat the following result from Debug error:
2024-08-18 05:14:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-wghp7.wghservers.com ESMTP Exim 4.97.1 #2 Sun, 18 Aug 2024 06:14:11 +0100 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2024-08-18 05:14:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO agrop.co
2024-08-18 05:14:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-wghp7.wghservers.com Hello agrop.co [131.153.147.178]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-PIPECONNECT250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
2024-08-18 05:14:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2024-08-18 05:14:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2024-08-18 05:14:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2024-08-18 05:14:11
2024-08-18 05:14:11
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.


Ensure that the endpoint email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com is reachable from your server. For that you need to run this command
telnet email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com 587

After much research, I am finally able to resolve the issue, I will like to drop it here to help anyone with the same issue in future.
In my AWS SES, I verified only email identity (as I have done for a lot of other host) but my current host (go54.com) is not resolving the peer certificate to the AWS verified email.
The solution that worked for me is verifying the domain as an identity on ASW SES and setting the DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) provided by AWS SES on my host Zone Records. The domain then get verified (after a while).
DKIM-signed messages help receiving mail servers validate that a message was not forged or altered in transit.
With this my initial code work just fine. I hope this help someone.
Thank you all for your help. KEEP CODING

You can see from the debug output that it’s connecting ok, so the SMTP host is available, and the problem does not lie with firewalls or port numbers. The problem occurs when switching to TLS after issuing STARTTLS, and this is usually caused by misnamed mail servers, transparent redirection, or invalid certificates. This specific scenario is covered extensively in the docs. You will need to set SMTPDebug to 3 or 4 to see what the issue is.

When I set SMTPDebug to 3 and 4 I get the error that:
Peer certificate CN=wghp7.wghservers.com' did not match expected CN=email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'

That looks like redirection - you are asking it to connect to one hostname, but it’s being intercepted and being connected to another one, so the certificate doesn’t match. You should check your hosting provider’s policy on outbound SMTP.

Don’t be tempted to disable certificate verification – fix the problem properly

Your SMTP host seems to be unavailable. It could be caused due issue with credentials. Please verify that your credentials + SSL/TLS are correct.
In code setup
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;

Check in firewall that you have outbound connections on port 587. Furthermore for Debugging purpose you can enable debug.
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

Please check in your logs.
